# Onclick, not working on any android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html

I hope someone can help me, I am having a little trouble with onclick tabs. All my tabs work on IOS devices but not android. I got the code from W3Sschools, here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 next-slider">

               <ul class="tab tab-content">

                 <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'ROOMS')">ROOMS</a></li>
                 <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'MEALS')">MEALS</a></li>
                 <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'FACILITIES')">FACILITIES</a></li>
                 <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'VISITING')">VISITING</a></li>
                 <li><a class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'SOCIAL')">SOCIAL</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ROOMS" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>ROOMS</h3>
  <p>All single bedrooms, most en-suite. All bedrooms are tastefully decorated and have a TV and nurse call bell. If residents wish they can bring some of their personal items and furniture.</p >
</div>

<div id="MEALS" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>MEALS</h3>
  <p>We offer a very extensive menu of home cooked meals including popular dishes such as hotpot, shepherds pie and fish &amp; chips every Friday.  Residents have a say when planning these and may take meals in their rooms when required.  Special diets are catered for.</p>
</div>

<div id="FACILITIES" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>FACILITIES</h3>
  <p>Each floor has its own large lounge and spacious dining room over-looking the Bay.  Bath/shower rooms situated on all floors, easy wheelchair access throughout the building. Ground floor is Residential Care and the first, second and third floors are Nursing Care.</p>
</div>

<div id="VISITING" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>VISITING</h3>
  <p>Relatives and friends are welcome at any time throughout the day. (We do ask that residents are not disturbed at mealtimes.) If you require any further details please do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
</div>

<div id="SOCIAL" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>SOCIAL</h3>
  <p>There are regular activities organised by our own Social Activities Organiser, Jacqui.  These include 
    Bingo, which is held twice a week and various other classes such as Painting, Music &amp; Movement, Crafts, Quizzes and Reminiscing of Past Times.</p>
  <p>An entertainer attends The Sands once a month, singing the residents' favourite songs.
    Pantomimes are held at Christmas time, and charity fund-raising events are held throughout the year, in which residents are welcome to get involved.</p>
  <p><strong>Monday</strong><br>
    Bingo
    1.30 pm     Keswick Suite Lounge </p>
  <p><strong>Tuesday</strong><br>
    Word Games
    10.15 am    Grasmere Suite Lounge <br>
    Music &amp; Movement
    1.30pm  Derwent Suite Lounge </p>
  <p><strong>Thursday</strong><br>
    Painting or Dominoes
    10.15 am    Keswick Suite Dining Room </p>
  <p><strong>Friday</strong><br>
    Reminiscence Group
    10.15 am    Keswick Suite Lounge<br>
    Bingo
    1.30 pm     Keswick Suite Lounge</p>
</div>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
</script>
```

I'm not sure but i have a js file with:

```
// JavaScript Document

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

If anyone have help i would be ever so grateful.

Kind regards,

James

Comment: What is this "event" that you pass in? `onclick="openCity(event, 'ROOMS')"`

Comment: What version of Android and what browser on Android are you testing on?

Comment: I have tried onclick="(function(){openCity(event, 'ROOMS');})()" but sadly it is not working. It works on every platform but not android. I am testing it on Android 6.0.1 with Google Chrome and on a Galaxy Tab A.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
onclick="(function(){openCity(event, 'ROOMS');})()"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.